# Arbeit mit und am/an dem Stein?

Tags: preposition, article

Ein Bildhauer verwandelt einen großen Gesteinsbrocken in eine Skulptur. Er arbeitet also mit dem Stein, aber auch an dem Stein, wofür man kürzer auch »am Stein« sagen kann.

Ist diese Verkürzung von »an dem« zu »am« auch dann erlaubt, wenn der in Wort »*am*« implizit enthaltene Artikel »*dem*« gleichzeitig auch zu einer anderen Präposition gehört?

Das sind die beiden Aussagen, die in einem Satz untergebracht werden sollen:

> Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit dem Stein.
>   Der Bildhauer arbeitet am Stein.

Bei dieser Version bin ich mir ziemlich sicher, dass sie korrekt ist:

> Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit und **an dem** Stein.

Bei der folgenden Version bin ich unsicher:

> Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit und **am** Stein.

---

### Nachtrag:

Nach der Lektüre einer Antwort wurde mir bewusst, dass der Satz

> Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit und am Stein.

Auch so interpretiert werden kann:

> a) Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit Stein. (Mit einem bestimmten Material)
>   b) Der Bildhauer arbeitet am Stein. (An einem bestimmten Stein)

Das war aber nicht gemeint. Gemeint war vielmehr:

> a) Der Bildhauer arbeitet **mit dem** Stein (der am 5. November 2015 in der Nähe von Horn im Waldviertel aus dem Berg gebrochen wurde, und nun im Atelier des Künstlers steht).
>   a) Der Bildhauer arbeitet **an dem** Stein (der am 5. November 2015 in der Nähe von Horn im Waldviertel aus dem Berg gebrochen wurde, und nun im Atelier des Künstlers steht).

Es ist also auch im Fall von *mit* der ganz konkrete Felsbrocken gemeint, der gerade vom Künstler behauen wird. Es ist nicht das generische Material Stein gemeint.

Ich formuliere den Satz daher um:

> Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit und **am** Felsbrocken, der ihm vor zwei Wochen geliefert wurde.

Kann hier das Wort *am* stehen bleiben, oder muss es durch *an dem* ersetzt werden?

> Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit und **an dem** Felsbrocken, der ihm vor zwei Wochen geliefert wurde.

Comment: Hubert, das ändert nichts. Auch in diesem Fall ist *mit Felsbrocken* eine Materialangabe, nur eben im Plural. Setzt du einen erklärenden Halbsatz dahinter, driftest du in Twainsche Untiefen ab. Um das zu verhindern, müsstest du tatsächlich *mit dem und an dem* schreiben und das *an dem* nicht zusammenziehen. Dann aber aus Gründen des Gleichklangs.

Comment: Bliebe noch die Möglichkeit "mit dem und am". Meinem Gefühl nach hört sich die Reihenfolge "am und mit dem" aber flüssiger an.

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin mir da gar nicht unsicher. Es geht und ist nach meinem Sprachgefühl in vielen Fällen sogar zwingend erforderlich.

> Der Fußballspieler bewegt sich zum und gegen den Gegner.
>
> Sie fuhr mit dem einen zum anderen Zug.
>
> Machen wir es mit und zum Spaß!

---

Kommt deine Unsicherheit vielleicht daher, dass in deinem Beispiel

> Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit und am Stein.

der erste Stein ein Material und der zweite Stein ein konkretes Objekt ist?

Solche semantischen Unterschiede gehen beim Sprechen leicht unter. Das heißt, selbst wenn es eine solche Regel gäbe, würde sie irgendwann niemand mehr beachten.

Comment: Seine Frage bezieht sich doch darauf, ob man *an dem* in *am* verkürzen darf, nicht ob eine und-Verknüpfung zweier Präpositionen generell möglich ist?

Comment: So hatte ich das auch verstanden. Es sind in Huberts Beispiel aber zwei unterschiedliche Arten Steine. Einmal der Stein als solches und einmal ein konkreter Stein.

Comment: @Janka: Wäre das Material Stein, oder, wie du es formulierst, *der Stein als solches* gemeint, würde man *am* nicht als *an dem*, sondern als *an einem* interpretieren, und dann würde die Verkürzung erst recht nicht möglich sein, weil die Bestimmtheiten nicht zusammenpassen (einmal bestimmt, das andere Mal unbestimmt). In meinem Beispiel ist aber derselbe und sehr konkrete Waldviertler Granitbrocken gemeint, der an einem ganz bestimmten Tag aus dem Berg gesprengt wurde, und jetzt unter dem Meißel des Künstlers seine Form verändert.

Comment: @Janka: Das Beispiel mit dem Fußballspieler ist anders konstruiert als mein Beispiel. Im Fußballsatz stehen zwei verschiedene Artikel (einmal implizit im Wort *zum*, das andere explizit als *den*), die noch dazu in zwei unterschiedlichen Fällen stehen (Dativ und Akkusativ). Die Besonderheit in diesem Satz ist das Substantiv, das in zwei Fällen zugleich steht. In meinem Beispiel steht das Substantiv ganz eindeutig in nur einem Fall (Dativ), aber es gibt nur einen Artikel, der implizit im Wort »*am*« versteckt ist, und trotzdem auch zur Präposition »*mit*« gehören möchte.

Comment: @Janka: Auch der Zug-Beispielsatz passt nicht zu meinem Satz. Es geht nicht darum, ob ein doppeltes Substantiv eingespart werden darf. Das steht ja außer Zweifel. Es geht darum, ob ein Artikel, der in einer Verkürzung wie *zum, im, am, aufs, zur*, usw. versteckt ist, trotzdem als zusätzlich auch zu einer anderen Präposition gehörend interpretiert werden kann. - Auch der Spaß-Satz hat nichts mit meinem Beispielsatz gemein.

Comment: Wenn du schreibst: *Der Bildhauer arbeitet mit Stein.* so ist *Stein* das Material. Schreibst du hingegen *Der Bildhauer arbeitet an dem Stein* oder *Der Bildhauer arbeitet am Stein* so ist in beiden Fällen ein bestimmter Stein gemeint. Verheiratest du das in einem Satz mit *und*, musst du darüber hinwegsehen, dass es zwei verschiedene Steine sind. Ich habe damit aber überhaupt kein Problem und deute den zusammengefassten Satz genau wie die Einzelsätze.